# Create drupal commerce product with external script: problem with custom fields

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm trying to create drupal commerce product from php script. I've used for this task sample function from commerce_examples module.

Everything is working well except two things: I can't add values to the custom datetime field field_valid (it has two values "datetime from" and "datetime to") and term reference to the category field field_category.

I can get category tid, but I don't know how to add value to the field.

Please help me with it, because I tried everything I could find in the Internet, but still didn't have any success.

I have array of product fields values

```
$extras = array(
    'sku' => 'stf_' . $value->id,
    'status' => TRUE,
    'uid' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid,
    'title' => $value->name,
    'price' => $value->pricecoupon,
    'start_time' => $value->start_time, // value: 2012-05-14 03:00:00
    'end_time' => $value->end_time, // value: 2012-05-14 03:00:00
    'category' => $value->category, // value: MyCategory
);

function product_example_create_product($product_type, $extras) {
    $form_state = array();
    $form_state['values'] = array();
    $form = array();
    $form['#parents'] = array();

    // Generate a new product object
    $new_product = commerce_product_new($product_type);

    $new_product->status = $extras['status'];
    $new_product->uid = $extras['uid'];

    $new_product->sku = $extras['sku'];
    $new_product->title = $extras['title'];
    $new_product->created = $new_product->changed = time();

    $price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array(
        'amount' => $extras['price'] * 100,
        'currency_code' => commerce_default_currency(),
    )));
    $form_state['values']['commerce_price'] = $price;

    if(!empty( $extras['category'])) {
        // Get category term tid
        $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($extras['category'], 'catalog');
        $tid = term[1]->tid;
       // HERE I NEED TO ADD CATEGORY REFERENCE
    }

// HERE I TRIED TO ADD DATETIME FIELD
//  list($date_from, $time_from) = split('[ ]', $extras['start_time']);
//  list($date_to, $time_to) = split('[ ]', $extras['end_time']);

//  $form_state['values']['field_valid'] = array(LANGUAGE_NONE =>array(0 => array('value' => array('date' => $date_from, 'time' => $time_from), 'value2' => array('date' => $date_to, 'time' => $time_to))));

    // Notify field widgets to save their field data
    field_attach_submit('commerce_product', $new_product, $form, $form_state);

    commerce_product_save($new_product);
    return $new_product->product_id;
}
```

UPD: Here is solution

```
if(!empty( $extras['category'])) {
// TODO: check if correct tid was received and add default tid with message to manager
// TODO: Make workaround for multiple category instances
    $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($extras['category'], 'catalog');
    $form_state[ 'values' ][ 'field_category' ] = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('tid' => $term[1]->tid)));
}

$form_state['values']['field_valid'] = array(LANGUAGE_NONE =>array(0 => array(
    'value' => $extras['start_time'],
    'value2' => $extras['end_time'],
    'timezone' => 'Europe/Kiev',
    'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
    'date_type' => 'datetime'
)));
```